# How to count push events on GitHub using BigQuery?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the public GitHub dataset on BigQuery to count events - PushEvents, in this case - on a per repository basis over time.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE type = 'PushEvent' 
    AND repository_name = "account/repo"
GROUP BY pushed_at
ORDER BY pushed_at DESC
```

Basically just retrieve the count for a specified repo and event type, group the count by date and return the list. BigQuery validates the following, but then fails the query with a:

```
Field 'pushed_at' not found.
```

As far as I can tell from GitHub's PushEvent [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), however, pushed_at is an available field. Anybody have examples of related queries that execute properly? Any suggestions as to what's being done incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is called repository_pushed_at, and you also probably meant to include it in the SELECT list, i.e.

```
SELECT repository_pushed_at, COUNT(*)
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE type = 'PushEvent' 
    AND repository_name = "account/repo"
GROUP BY repository_pushed_at
ORDER BY repository_pushed_at DESC
```

Comment: I did indeed, thanks! That gives me results, but the account/repo format kicks out. Do you know how to specify the account? Is it repository_owner or similar?

Update: looks like that's it indeed. Thanks for the original answer!

Comment: You can view the table schema at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/githubarchive:github.timeline if you are curious what fields are present.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Danny. Had been hunting for that, unsuccessfully.